# GTM + Analytic mobile

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Why I have no any data on GA view?
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'

All write/copy like in manual (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/)

```
   void tagManagerInit() {
    tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
    tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID,
                    R.raw.gtm_xxxxx);
    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("CuteAnimals", "failure loading container");
                return;
            }
            ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
           tagManagerFill();
        }
    }, TIMEOUT_FOR_CONTAINER_OPEN_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

my Tag:

**Choose Product**

GA

**Configure Tag**

Tag Type
Universal Analytics

Tracking ID

UA-XXXXXXXXX-X

Enable Advertising ID Features
True

Track Type
App View

**Fire On**
Any Event

above fillData some push event(copypast + random):

```
void tagManagerFill() {
    Log.v("GoogleTagManager", "startFill");
    DataLayer dataLayer = tagManager.getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event", "transaction",
            "transactionId", 1,
            "transactionTotal", 2,
            "transactionAffiliation", "In-app",
            "transactionTax", 4,
            "transactionShipping", 5,
            "transactionCurrency", "USD",
            "transactionProducts", 6));
    dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event", "openScreen", "screenName", "eyrtyertyert456734yrtyerty"));

    dataLayer.pushEvent("OpenScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", "354235")); 
    ....
```

**Logcat:**

```
I/GoogleTagManager: Obtained fresh AdvertisingId info from GmsCore.
W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 83ms
V/GoogleTagManager: Attempting to load a container from the resource ID 2131165184 (<<pck_name>>:raw/gmt_<<xxxx>>)
V/GoogleTagManager: Deleted 0 expired items
W/GoogleTagManager: Failed to extract the container from the resource file. Resource is a UTF-8 encoded string but doesn't contain a JSON container
V/GoogleTagManager: The container was successfully loaded from the resource (using binary file)
E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
V/GoogleTagManager: Attempting to load resource from disk
V/GoogleTagManager: loadAfterDelay: containerId=GTM-<<ID>> delay=35716824
D/GoogleTagManager: Setting previous container version: NQ$0
E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
V/GoogleTagManager: The Disk resource was successfully read.
I/GoogleTagManager: Obtained fresh AdvertisingId info from GmsCore.
W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 53ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you supplying a screenName in fields to set? Universal Analytics tags require a screenName for tracking types appView.

Comment: no. But why don't send data about phone and user? It's no collect automatically?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I looked only at Real-time data. But anyway, RT don't display users in this case :(

Comment: Google Analytics tags do include some phone characteristics, but screen views won't be considered as valid without a screen name, and therefore none of the data sent with the screen view will be shown in reports or real time.

Comment: could I use GTM v5 only for logging, without setting up Firebase? Currently need only GA account, but GTM v5 supported little bit more external systems.

Comment: and what is  analog "Data Layer Variable"  for GTM v5

Comment: The analog of the DataLayer in v5 is Firebase Analytics' logEvent calls. Using Firebase Analytics also gets you built in tracking of deep links, conversions, etc.

Comment: analog in GTM(when choose new Variable).